# Ratings not updating as expected in Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to implement a rating system along the lines of upvotes/downvotes.
Users can vote on a lesson only once. They can switch their votes between up and down. Voting the same as their previous vote removes their vote.
I'm trying to accomplish this with pull() but it empties out the entire ratings array including other users' votes.

#### Rating Schema

```
var RatingSchema = new Schema({
  rating: Boolean,
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});
```

#### Lesson Schema

```
var LessonSchema = new Schema({
    ...,
    ratings: [RatingSchema]
});
```

#### Problem code

```
//assuming lesson.ratings looks like this
[{user: 123..., rating: true},
 {user: 321..., rating: true}];
//assuming lesson was loaded from a query
lesson.ratings.pull({user: 123...});
//resulting ratings
[]
```

I don't if this is expected behavior but I just want to remove the matching rating and not all of the sub docs.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reduce your problem down to a minimal example that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thanks for replying. I reduced the problem. I don't know if this is reproducible by everyone. mongoose version 3.8.3 if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working sol'n.
The problem was the way the rating schema was originally defined and [how save() works](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/):

#### OG Rating Schema

```
var Ratings = new Schema({
  _id: false,
  rating: Boolean,
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});
```

I thought the user ref would be unique enough to work with wrt modifying ratings.
I still don't know why the pull() would delete all subdocs regardless of user id.
When its time to save, because of the lack of _id, it updated the entire ratings array overwriting altogether.
To fix this instead of using the user to update, I switched it to use _id.
Also, careful when switching the _id flag on and off again. The driver will throw undefined objectid errs.